# What's the meaning of "iter(lambda : object() > object(), object())"

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, iterator

When I run this iterator:

```
iter(lambda : object() > object(), object())
```

the iterator continuously outputs `True` and `False`.

But what's the meaning of that and how is it executed?

Comment: It seems like a purposefully silly way of creating an infinite iterator that alternatives between `True` and `False`. It is also only going to work on Python 2, and even there, it is relying on an implementation detail.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'd like to know why it happens. Care to write an answer?

Comment: What do you not understand? Have you looked at the documentation? It uses all built-in functions... [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons) is the final hint, something that isn't obvious. Indeed, all of that changed in Python 3 because the behavior is less than ideal. Comparisons between types that don't support comparisons should error out, not have some arbitrary default ordering that is an implementation detail...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Why it alternates between `True` and `False`, and why it considers `object()`s to be orderable...

Comment: Because in Python 2, unfortunately: "CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address."

Comment: Thank you for the link. I got that. But you'd expect random True and False sequences, not a perfect alternating sequence...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The two-argument `iter` keeps calling the callable you pass as the first argument until the sentinel value, the second argument, is encountered. Well, that sentinel will *never* be encountered, since the callable returns a `bool`, and a `bool` is never equal to an `object()`. Essentially, since `object()`s are ordered by their `id()` you *would* expect random sequences of `True` and `False`, at least that is all we could guarantee. But Python reuses memory addresses of objects that are recently garbage-collected.

Comment: There's the aha! Write that as an answer and I'll upvote it. :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. I tested a bit more, and it didn't always toggel between `True` and `False`.

Comment: There's always a pattern.  It changes each time you redefine the iterator. Sometimes that pattern is always True or always False.  But there's always a pattern.

Answer (score 6):

As already stated in the comments this is an implementation detail and it just "happens" to give an alternating sequence of `True` and `False` (however, one cannot predict if the first one is `True` or `False`).

Let's start with some facts about CPython 2.7:

- If an object in python-2.x doesn't implement `__eq__` and is compared to another object of the same type it compares the memory adresses.
- Some memory adresses are re-used in a LIFO (last-in first-out) fashion

Let's have a look at that iterator of yours, this time with a not-lambda function and `print`s for the memory addresses:

```
def cmp_objects():
    a = object()
    b = object()
    print id(a)
    print id(b)
    print a > b

x = iter(cmp_objects, object())
next(x), next(x), next(x), next(x), next(x)
```

which gives:

```
69637872
69638064
False
69638064
69637872
True
69637872
69638064
False
69638064
69637872
True
69637872
69638064
False
```

So the `a` variable starts with a memory address of `69637872` and `b` with `69638064`. Because the memory address of `b` is bigger this returns `False`. In the next call the memory addresses are swapped (remember LIFO), and so on.

Because the memory address of the sentinel (second argument to `iter`) is different from the memory adress of `True` and `False` the loop never stops and gives alternating `True` and `False`.

---

However, a better way to get such a sequence would be:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> it = itertools.cycle((True, False))
```

That also has a predictable first yielded value. It also doesn't break if `object`s are created between `next` calls:

```
>>> x = iter(lambda : object() > object(), object())
>>> next(x)
True
>>> object()
<object at 0x4269610>
>>> next(x)
True
```

This example may give different results, this way the result is totally random!